# Tikz, Tangent Line to a Circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles

[image]

Why is the tangent not really horizontal?

```
     \documentclass{article}
     \usepackage{tikz}
     \usepackage{circuitikz}
     \usepackage{pst-solides3d}
     \usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations}
     \usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
     \tikzset{
     state/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=6ex},
     arrow/.style={-latex, shorten >=1ex, shorten <=1ex}}
     \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}  
     \node[name=D,draw,circle,inner sep=3pt,fill=gray!50] at (17,.5) {};
     %d
     \draw
     (D.north) to (16.65,.65)
     (D.south) to (16.65,.35)
     ;
     \draw[latex-]
     (16.75,.65) to (16.75,1);
     \draw[latex-]
     (16.75,.35) to (16.75,0);
     \node at (16.45,.5) {$d$};
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The image is twice here;-)

Comment: It's all to do with line width.  The position `D.north` is on the very outside of the circle, so the middle of your incident line is aligned with the outside of the circle line.  There are a couple of ways to solve this depending on how technical you are prepared to be.

Comment: (I think we've seen this before, but for a rectangle node shape.  The solutions for that ought to be applicable here, but my search skills are sadly lacking.)

Comment: Holy.... I always forget this gold badge thingy. Please let us know if it is not a duplicate, though adding `outer sep=0mm` would solve it.

Comment: I almost got to post this ;(: You could use relative locations: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
  state/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=6ex},
  arrow/.style={-latex, shorten >=1ex, shorten <=1ex}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[name=D,draw,circle,inner sep=3pt,fill=gray!50] at (17,.5) {};
 %d
 \draw
 (D.north) -- +(-.35,0)
 (D.south) -- +(-.35,0)
 ;
 \draw[latex-]
 (16.75,.65) to (16.75,1);
 \draw[latex-]
 (16.75,.35) to (16.75,0);
 \node at (16.45,.5) {$d$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`